# ColdFusion return data from CFC in jquery to build a related select not working

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfml

Trying to get a simple related select working with a CFC and jquery, and it seems like it should be working, but I keep getting undefined errors.

The first select sends the state to a CFC which returns and array of IDs and college names - this seems to be working (just showing the ajax call as it's working fine past here)

```
$.ajax({ 
    method: 'post', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    url: compath + '/remote.cfc', 
    data: { 
      method: 'querySchoolsByState', 
      returnFormat: 'json', 
      school_state: $selStateShort 
    },
    dataFilter: function(data, type){
      //CF has // set as security prefix
      return type == 'json' ? data.replace(/^(\/{2})?/, '') : data;
    },
    success: 
        function(results,status,xhr){ 
        var $schoolSelect = $('#school');
        $schoolSelect.find('option:not(:first)').remove();
        if (results.length){ 
          console.log(results.length);
          console.log(results); 
          $.each (results, function(i){ 
            console.log(results[i].co_coid); 
            $collegeSelect.append('<option value="' + results[i].co_coid + '">' + results[i].co_name + '</option>'); 
        });
```

The first two console logs work as expected - length and the actual json data:

[image]

This one (console.log(results[i].co_coid);) just gives undefined.

I'm curious if this is related to the dataFilter not working and Chrome Dev Tools handling the //, but the code not handling it.  If I look at the Network tab I do see the // prefix:

[image]

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. The CF key names are in upper case, so your JS references should use CO_COID, etc...

Comment: I KNEW it was something stupid that I missed!!  Thank you!

Comment: Can one of you post that as the answer so @Steve can accept it?

Comment: Case-sensitivity can be fun. Working with Javascript will definitely get you in the habit of paying attention to casing, but I can't tell you how many hours I lost early in my career troubleshooting why my application variables weren't working, only to find out that our app was moved to a Linux host and I had `application.cfm` instead of `Application.cfm`. :-/

Comment: @Steve - Feel free to write it up as an answer with the corrected code snippet. I am too lazy to do it on my phone ;-)

Comment: @Ageax Since you were too lazy, I threw something up for you. :-)

Comment: @Shawn - Cool, have at it :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a quick illustration of how ColdFusion functions work with case-sensitivity (especially with JSON).

```
<cfscript>
    function testJSON() returnFormat="JSON" {
        var retVal = {
            imlower : "lowercase" ,
            IMUPPER : "UPPERCASE" ,
            ImMixed : "Mixed Case" ,
            "ImQuoted" : "Quoted Case"
        } ;

        return serializeJSON(retVal) ;
    }

    function testNoJSON() {
        var retVal = {
            imlower : "lowercase" ,
            IMUPPER : "UPPERCASE" ,
            ImMixed : "Mixed Case" ,
            "ImQuoted" : "Quoted Case"
        } ;

        return retVal ;
    }
    writeDump(testJSON());
    writeDump(testNoJSON());
</cfscript>
```

This returns the JSON string `{"IMUPPER":"UPPERCASE","IMMIXED":"Mixed Case","IMLOWER":"lowercase","ImQuoted":"Quoted Case"}` and a ColdFusion Structure. Both showing the key names being upper-cased (except when quoted).

So, CF will upper-case keys unless they are quoted. Since an application might interact with a lot of different types of technology or systems that handle case-sensitivity differently, it's important to understand what a variable looks like when it comes out of a function. If you're going to be working with Javascript (which IS case-sensitive), it's sometimes a good idea to just make all of the variables upper-case so you never think you're passing `ImMixed` when you're actually passing `IMMIXED`.

https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=97aaf3fa-4cd5-4579-9ee8-2fa1314d3304/d8e80b02-8ebb-40b2-8be8-1a08ff36c343/d0e94bc5-d19b-424c-9cd4-cab999c4c8df.cfm

Comment: .. and if for some reason you're using dot notation, it's *always* converted upper case, as well.

Comment: @Ageax Good point. I updated my Fiddle with a couple more examples.